# Uniquely identifying multiple Epson thermal printers

Tags: printer, raspberry-pi, cups, raspbian

I'm planning to connect multiple Epson thermal printers (TM-T88V) to a Raspberry Pi 3, running Raspbian.

The Raspberry Pi 3 will act as a web application server and print server for three iPads at a kiosk.

So my web application will process HTTP requests from the iPads. The web application can tell which iPad made which request, because I can make my WiFi router associate a static IP to each iPad's MAC address, and then my web app can see the IP by examining the HTTP header. So when it's time to print, I want to send the print job to the corresponding thermal printer installed next to each iPad.

But if the printers are all of the same model, is there a way I can uniquely identify each of them? I don't think /dev/bus/usb paths will be good enough, because I don't trust the person doing the final assembly.

Comment: If you rule out usb paths, the only chance is if the printer have some sort of model number they can report, and that varies from printer type to printer type. Do you already have at least one of those printers so you can test? What driver is needed for them? Any interesting in `dmesg` after you connect one?

Comment: If you get them with an ethernet i/f you can give each a unique IP address, and just plug them into the WiFi router. See for example https://possales.com.au/tm-t88v-edg-usb-ethernet.html